# Invalid syntax error in python script

Tags: python, cmd, helper

When trying to run a python script  with cmd it gives me this error "Invalid syntax".

Here's the code, and the invalid error is in line 3 "raise bla bla"

```
def make_chunk(tag, data):
    if len(tag) != 4:
      raise â€کYo!They call it â€œFourCCâ€‌ for a reason.â€™
    ret = struct.pack(â€ک>Lâ€™, len(data) + 8)
    ret += tag
    ret += data
    return ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code editor replaced single (`'` - [U+0027 APOSTROPHE](https://codepoints.net/U+0027)) and double (`"` - [U+0022 QUOTATION MARK](https://codepoints.net/U+0022)) ASCII quotes with 'fancy' quotes, specifically:

- `‘` - [U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://codepoints.net/U+2018)
- `’` - [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://codepoints.net/U+2019)
- `“` - [U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://codepoints.net/U+201C) and
- `”` - [U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://codepoints.net/U+201D)

You then saved the file as UTF-8, and tried to have Python run it.

Python doesn't support anything but the ASCII quotes for strings, so an exception was raised, and because your *console* is configured as [Windows codepage 1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) you see the weird [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) output:

```
>>> print u'\u2018 - \u2019 - \u201C - \u201D'
‘ - ’ - “ - ”
>>> u'\u2018 - \u2019 - \u201C - \u201D'.encode('utf8')
'\xe2\x80\x98 - \xe2\x80\x99 - \xe2\x80\x9c - \xe2\x80\x9d'
>>> print u'\u2018 - \u2019 - \u201C - \u201D'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1256')
â€ک - â€™ - â€œ - â€‌
```

Use a better (code) editor or tell the current editor to not replace simple quotes with fancy quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't answer your question, but it will solve your problem.

Download the exploit from github instead of exploit-db

https://gist.github.com/tfairane/fedb4881945bab998504#file-stagefright_cve-2015-1538-1_exploit-py-L6

Your welcome